# ADODB.Recordset error '800a0e78' Operation is not allowed when the object is closed. classic ASP

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp-classic

I know this is probably a dupe of another question but i really have no idea, i've searched all over and tried everything but it still seems to be giving me the same error of;

> ADODB.Recordset error '800a0e78'
>
> Operation is not allowed when the object is closed.

If someone could help me with this it would be greatly appreciated, I'm using classic ASP, SQL and HTML;

My classic ASP code is;

```vb
If(Request.Form("submitBtn"))<>""Then
  'Initialise the db connection
  Set objDBConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
  objDBConn.Open "Provider=sqloledb;Data Source=OLIVERBEELEY;Initial Catalog=HolidayEmployeeBooker;User ID=HBA;Password=HBA;"

  'Initialise the command object
  Set objDBCommand = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")

  objDBCommand.ActiveConnection = objDBConn
  objDBCommand.CommandText = "spNewHoliday"
  objDBCommand.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc

  'Set the parameters             
  objDBCommand.Parameters.Append objDBCommand.CreateParameter("@StartDate", adDate, adParamInput,200)
  objDBCommand.Parameters.Append objDBCommand.CreateParameter("@EndDate", adDate, adParamInput,200)
  objDBCommand.Parameters.Append objDBCommand.CreateParameter("@EmployeeID", adVarChar, adParamInput,200)            
  objDBCommand.Parameters.Append objDBCommand.CreateParameter("@Reason", adVarChar, adParamInput,200)

  objDBCommand("@StartDate") = Request.Form("from")
  objDBCommand("@EndDate") = Request.Form("to")
  objDBCommand("@EmployeeID") = Session("UserID")
  objDBCommand("@Reason") = Request.Form("comments")

  'Initialise the Recordset
  Set objDBRS = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")

  'Execute 
  objDBRS.open objDBCommand,,adOpenForwardOnly

  if not objDBRS.EOF then
    Session("BookingValid") = objDBRS(0)
  end if

  if Session("BookingValid") = "ErrorBookingHoliday" then
     response.Write("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=""JavaScript"">alert(""Holiday CANNOT be booked."");</SCRIPT>")
  end if
  if Session("BookingValid") = "ErrorBookingHoliday" then
     response.Write("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=""JavaScript"">alert(""Holiday has been requested."");</SCRIPT>")
  end if

  'Close and Destroy Objects - Start*******************************************************
  Set objDBCommand=nothing
  objDBConn.Close
  Set objDBConn=nothing
  'Close and Destroy Objects - End*********************************************************

  response.redirect("newbooking.asp")

end if 


%>
```

My Stored procedure its calling are;

```
PROCEDURE [dbo].[spNewHoliday]
(
@StartDate DATE,
@EndDate DATE,
@EmployeeID INT,
@Reason NVARCHAR (45)
)


AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
BEGIN



IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 
                FROM Holidays
                WHERE @StartDate = StartDate
                AND @EndDate = EndDate
                AND @EmployeeID = EmployeeID)

                BEGIN
                DECLARE @Validation INT
                    EXEC spBusinessRuleValidation @StartDate, @EndDate, @EmployeeID, @Validation OUTPUT


                    IF @Validation = 0
                        BEGIN
                            DECLARE @DaysOff AS INT
                            SELECT @DaysOff = (DATEDIFF(Day,@StartDate,@EndDate) +1)

                            UPDATE Employees
                            SET AnnualDaysHolidayAllowance = AnnualDaysHolidayAllowance - @DaysOff
                            WHERE @EmployeeID = Employees.ID                

                            INSERT INTO Holidays(EmployeeID, StartDate, EndDate, Duration, Status, Reason)
                            VALUES(@EmployeeID, @StartDate, @EndDate, @DaysOff,'Pending', @Reason)

                            SELECT Employees.AnnualDaysHolidayAllowance AS Daysleft FROM Employees WHERE @EmployeeID = Employees.ID
                        END
                        SET NOCOUNT ON
                    IF @Validation = 1
                        BEGIN
                            SELECT 'ErrorBookingHoliday' AS FailedBooking
                        END
                END

END
```

And the stored procedure that, that procedure is calling is;

```
PROCEDURE [dbo].[spBusinessRuleValidation]
(
@StartDate DATE,
@EndDate DATE,
@EmployeeID INT,
@Validation INT output
)

AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @JobRoleID INT
        DECLARE @MaxJobTypeAllowedOff INT       
        DECLARE @MaxEmployeesAllowedOff INT
        DECLARE @DateCount INT
        DECLARE @SameJobRoleOff INT
        DECLARE @DateCheck DATE

        SET @JobRoleID = (SELECT JobRoleID FROM Employees WHERE @EmployeeID = Employees.ID)
        SET @MaxJobTypeAllowedOff = (SELECT MaxEmployeesAllowedOff FROM JobRole WHERE @JobRoleID = JobRole.ID)
        SET @MaxEmployeesAllowedOff = 20
        SET @DateCheck = @StartDate
        SET @EndDate = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @EndDate)
        SET @Validation = '0'

        WHILE (@DateCheck <> @EndDate)
        BEGIN
            SET @DateCount = (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM Holidays WHERE Holidays.Startdate >= @DateCheck AND Holidays.EndDate <= @EndDate )
            IF @DateCount > @MaxEmployeesAllowedOff
                BEGIN
                    SET @Validation = '1'
                    BREAK
                END

            SET @SameJobRoleOff = (SELECT COUNT (*) JobRoleID
            FROM Employees
            RIGHT JOIN Holidays
            ON Employees.ID = Holidays.EmployeeID
            WHERE Employees.ID = @EmployeeID AND Holidays.Startdate >= @DateCheck AND Holidays.EndDate <= @EndDate AND Holidays.Status <> 'Declined')

            IF @SameJobRoleOff > @MaxJobTypeAllowedOff
                BEGIN
                    SET @Validation = '1'
                    BREAK
                END

            SET @DateCheck = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @DateCheck)
        END
    END
```

I am very new to SQL and ASP (about 3-4 months of experience) and need some help with this problem, any help would be appreciated even if its just to do with code that isnt the cause of my error! Thanks! OH this is the code where it goes wrong!

```
if not objDBRS.EOF then
  Session("BookingValid") = objDBRS(0)
end if
```

Comment: the procedures are called because the data i input is added to the database meaning the calls do not fail so theres that, and as the ASP shows the connection is open, and what other code would you need to see, all my other ASP code is calling other functions which do not create errors? @TomTom

Comment: Ah, no. As the error is not related to any SQL it is irrelevant.

Comment: the code in visual studio isn't commented out, its the way its been put into stackoverflow and how their commenting system works, i'm not that stupid that i comment out code that opens and closes DB connections, and also it must be the SQL because thats what breaks the code, i believe its to do with the SQL procedures returning the Validation variable incorrectly but i'm most likely wrong @TomTom

Comment: Check how the recordset looks like when you get it back. And you won't get a ton of help here, I think - you basically use museum level technology. Man, it is like 15 years since I last saw an adodb recordset.

Comment: Yeah thats the problem, it doesn't get into the recordset because its saying its not open? which is why i'm asking for help in the first place...not whether i use code that people haven't seen for years @TomTom

Comment: is spNewHoliday returning any record when you execute it via SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: Its hard to run it in SQL because of the data it needs, i just get a Commands completed successfully, when i run it through my site, i can add a holiday to the database fine, its just when i try to add a holiday which breaks the rules i get the error so im really stumped. @kloarubeek

Comment: You definitely want to know what this SP returns, because if it doesn't return anything, your recordset is closed = your error message! Why is it so hard? It depends on 4 parameters! Run the SQL Profiler while executing your code, then it's easy to get the correct parameters. An alternative: check for objDBRS.State before your .EOF check, the value is probably 0 (adStateClosed). I didn't check your stored procedure completely, but I think it has some return paths that don't return anything.

Comment: From what I can see in your `[dbo].[spNewHoliday]` stored procedure there are at least 1 possible point where you could get a no recordset returned, which might be your problem.

Comment: Which point are you looking at? @Lankymart

Comment: @Jimmy_Chong At your `IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM Holidays WHERE @StartDate = StartDate AND @EndDate = EndDate AND @EmployeeID = EmployeeID)` if it does exist no recordset will return.

Comment: @kloarubeek When i pass in the correct 4 parameters and exec that inside of SQL i get the query executed successfully but no other data passed back out to me.

Comment: @Lankymart I love you, the error message isn't showing up anymore but my custom error messages aren't returning in my html so looks like i've got a new task to work on :)

Comment: ok. If no records are returned, you can't check on .EOF. So first check if anything is returned with if objDBRS.State = adStateOpen Then ...

Answer (score 3):

I have a few SPs that return a one-row recordset at the end of their operation, using something like

```
      SELECT @some_symbol some_column_name;
```

If I omit `SET NOCOUNT ON` from those stored procedures, then my classic ASP adodb recordset isn't returned correctly, and I get the "object is closed" error.

If I include `SET NOCOUNT ON` in those stored procedures, things work correctly.

The same is true if I run an ordinary block of SQL, not a stored procedure, that works the same way.

As far as Classic ASP goes, I am definitely in the "why ask why?" camp. I just have to get my maintenance work done.

Comment: Thanks, it was this. And maybe that’s why SQL Server, for instance, has it in its template for a new procedure, commenting *“added to prevent extra result sets from interfering with SELECT statements”* …